# Tracking face mesh vertices of Augmented Faces (ARCore) regardless of rotation

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, mesh, arcore

I'm trying to track facial expressions such as eyebrow raise, smile, wink, etc. In ARKit I could use blendShapes (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfaceanchor/2928251-blendshapes) to detect the movement of the different parts of the face but in ARCore it doesn't exist yet.

I've tried to access the mesh vertices which are relative to the center transform of the face but these change significantly with the rotation of the face.

Is there a way to normalize the face landmark/vertex from 0 to 1 where 0 is neutral and 1 is the maximum facial expression? It doesn't need to be as accurate as ARKit blendShapes.

Comment: Sorry But unfortunate ARcore not supported Blend-shape animation because its required true depth camera , but if you want to achieve this thing you can use OpenCV C++ Dlib and compile it in .so and use it in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Your question talks of 2 separate problems:-

1. The problem of getting blendshapes from ARCore just like ARKit.
2. The problem of head rotation making the pointwise comparisons difficult.

I do not have a solution for the problem 1. However for problem 2, you can compute a rotation matrix from the landmark points. I have a method ready to do it for mediakit face mesh. Hope this works for you:-

```
def calc_rotation_matrix(self):
    left_corner_right_eye = get_left_corner_right_eye()
    right_corner_left_eye = get_right_corner_left_eye()
    left_corner_face = get_left_corner_face()
    right_corner_face = get_right_corner_face()
    upper_nose = get_upper_pt_nose()
    chin = get_chin()

    rotation_matrix = np.zeros((3, 3))
    rotation_matrix[0:] = (right_corner_face - left_corner_face) / np.linalg.norm(right_corner_face - left_corner_face)
    rotation_matrix[1:] = (chin - upper_nose) / np.linalg.norm(chin - upper_nose)
    rotation_matrix[2:] = np.cross(rotation_matrix[0, :], rotation_matrix[1, :])
    
    return rotation_matrix
```

You will obviously have to write the methods for getting the respective points for your own usecase. Once you have this rotation matrix, you can always get the face with (pitch, yaw, roll) = (0, 0, 0) by multiplying the landmarks by `np.linalg.inv(rotation_matrix)`

AFAIK MediaKit (or ARCore) does not have the feature of blendshapes built in. @Hardik mentions in the comment above that OpenCV and Dlib can help in this .. but I am not so sure. In fact, I am searching for something similar.