# Augmented reality Face Tracking

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I need to make an app like snapChat face filtering. I tried to use AR face filtering.

https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/AugmentedFace

Now i understand to implement face tracking. But what i do not found is how i can find the different parts of face like hair and nose etc. and place object on that.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Have you seen: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/augmented-faces-with-sceneform/#1

Comment: Possibly related: [Tracking face mesh vertices of Augmented Faces (ARCore) regardless of rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58226299/295004)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But can you tell me how they manage position like nose in the demo. Does it manage from .obj(3D object). or by java. Because in java there is no code